# Where are the Vue 3 / Vuex v4 dev tools in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs3, developer-tools, vuex4

I am working in a Vue 3 and Vuex 4 project and am in the process of creating my store for vuex but in Chrome **I am missing the dev tools to manage my vuex store.** I was able to do this with Vue 2 and Vuex 3.*. Is this something in the works?

Thank you.

Comment: First off, I need to say that Vue3 currently only works with the beta version of the Vue.js devtools, but I assume, you are already using this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg

Comment: AFAIK the store stuff is not ready yet, you might find some insight here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/kcefez/vuex_in_vue_devtools_on_vue_3/

Comment: Yes I have the latest chrome extension. I did end up seeing since I posted this question in the vuex/router docs that the team is currently working on getting this functional. Hopefully they get it out soon.